# Como entregar ligações na fila na ordem que os agentes fazem login?

Tags: asterisk

Eu tenho uma fila no asterisk onde a estratégia está no modo `leastrecent`.
Porém, tenho observado que a ordem que os atendentes fazem login na fila não é a mesma na hora de receber a primeira ligação.

A distribuição só funciona de fato após todos eles atenderem uma ligação e ficar com a informação do tempo de ocioso.

Enquanto isso, a distribuição acontece de forma aleatória para quem ainda não atendeu a primeira chamada.

Como fazer para as primeiras ligações serem entregues na ordem que fazem o login?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do asterisk, estratégia de toque `leastrecent` encaminha a próxima chamada para o agente mais ocioso, portanto acredito que não é o que você procura.

A estratégia que melhor se encaixa na necessidade descrita é a `linear`, que encaminha as chamadas para os agentes na mesma ordem em que eles foram adicionados à fila, ou seja a ordem em que eles fizeram login.

Fonte: [Repositório oficial do asterisk](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/configs/samples/queues.conf.sample)